# How can I keep two different columns in sync from two different tables?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, database-design

I have a `users` table, and I have an `oauth` table.
The `oauth` table consists three columns:

- user_id
- oauth_id
- oauth_provider

The purpose of the `oauth` table is to link provider ids to internal user ids and provide a unique identifier for each user.
I'm trying to get myself into a situation where I can sync the `id` column of the `users` with the `user_id` of `oauth`.
Something I tried:

node environment, node-postgres as the DB client.

```
export default function addUser(user: UserDetails) {
  const { displayName, phoneNumber, isDriver, oauthId, oauthProvider } = user;
  let query;
  query = {
    text:
      'INSERT INTO users(display_name, phone_number, is_driver) VALUES ($1, $2, $3);',
    values: [displayName, phoneNumber, isDriver]
  };
  executeQuery(query);
  query = {
    text:                                                           // Something Else?
      'INSERT INTO oauth(user_id, oauth_id, oauth_provider) VALUES ((select max(id) from users), $1, $2);',
    values: [oauthId, oauthProvider]
  };
  executeQuery(query);
}
```

This is risky and will not work if two requests are done at the same time.
What's the way to handle this type of situation? Thanks.

## EDIT

I think I found a solution, is this thread-safe?

```
export default async function addUser(user: UserDetails) {
  const { displayName, phoneNumber, isDriver, oauthId, oauthProvider } = user;
  let query;
  query = {
    text:
      'INSERT INTO users(display_name, phone_number, is_driver) VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING id;',
    values: [displayName, phoneNumber, isDriver]
  };
  const result = await executeQuery(query);

  if (result)
    query = {
      text:
        'INSERT INTO oauth(user_id, oauth_id, oauth_provider) VALUES ($1, $2, $3);',
      values: [result[0].id, oauthId, oauthProvider]
    };
  executeQuery(query);
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me. Taking it a step further, I would be to use Sequelize for this, as I believe you're re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you absolutely guarantee that this function will be the only way a new record will ever be written to the Users table, now and into the future? Yeah, I thought not.

Why wouldn't you want to create a way that guarantees that any record written to the Users table, from this or any other function anywhere in your app or any future app or any script run by any database developer or DBA, will also generate a corresponding record for the Oauth table?

To do that, simply create an `after insert` trigger on the Users table that inserts the proper row into the Oauth table. Then, no matter how a new user is created, the matching auth entry is also created.

There is the added benefit that, from the apps point of view, both inserts become part of the same transaction. So any problem writing a row to either table generates one exception and one rollback that means no changes are made to either table. This greatly simplifies error handling.

While you're doing that, create a `before delete` trigger to remove the corresponding Oauth entry whenever a user is removed. Same benefits.

Then you never have to worry about the Oauth table keeping in synch with the Users table. (For varying degrees of *never*, that is. But it will be pretty close.)

General rule of thumb: *perform necessary operations at the lowest possible level*. App code and stored procedures are high level, triggers, check constraints and domain definitions are low level.

Comment: Shouldn't the `user_id` in `oauth` be a foreign key of the `id` in `users`?

Comment: It certainly looks like it. Why?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the solution you have proposed, you could do both inserts in a single SQL statement using a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/queries-with.html):

```
WITH userinsert AS (
    INSERT INTO users(display_name, phone_number, is_driver) 
       VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO oauth(user_id, oauth_id, oauth_provider) 
    VALUES ((SELECT id FROM userinsert), $4, $5);
```

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of the `WITH` keyword.